# Is there a way to map a parent root class having multiple list classes-Including child classes using Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am able to create successful mapping but only one list class of parent root class gets mapped. From below code only List Designation class gets mapped while List Customfield class fails.

Mapping :`

```
  cfg.CreateMap<Emp,Designation>()
  .ForMember(a => a.desigs, b => b.ResolveUsing(c => c.designations));

  cfg.CreateMap<Emp, Employment>()
   .ForMember(a => a.role, b => b.ResolveUsing(c => c..firstname));

  cfg.CreateMap<RootObjectSource, RootObjectDest>()
   .ForMember(a => a.Customfield, b => b.ResolveUsing(c => c.Emp));

  cfg.CreateMap<Emp, Customfield>()
   .ForMember(x => x.Customfield, y => y.MapFrom(x => x.Id));
```

Source class:

```
 public class RootObjectSource
    {
        public List<Emp> employments{ get; set; }
    }

 public class Emp
    {
        public string Id{get; set;}
        public string Firstname{get; set;}
        public string Lastname{get; set;}
        public List<Desig> Desigs {get; set;}
    }

public class Desig
    {             
         public string role{ get; set; }
         public string salary{ get; set; }
    }

 Destination classes:

     public class RootObjectDest
      {
       public string principal{ get; set; }
       public List<Designation> designations{ get; set; }
       public List<Customfield> Customfield { get; set; }
      }

  public class Designation
     {             
              public List<Employment> employment { get; set; }
              public string role{ get; set; }
              public string salary{ get; set; }
     }
   public class Employment
    {
        public string Firstname{ get; set; }
        public string Lastname{ get; set; }
    }  
    public class Customfield
    { 
      public string stringfield{ get; set; }

    }
```

we need to map all list classes of destination class

Comment: This statement is very confusing: "only List class gets mapped while List class fails." In one brief sentence you're saying that something gets mapped and that it fails. What do you mean by "List class" and what do you mean by "fails?"

Comment: @scott - please read it again, stack overflow had hidden the words that were mentioned in <> brackets.

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. There are missing properties and names does not match. Please ensure that you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).